# Merge Request in Bitbucket: Possible to exempt a specific branch to ask for Merge Request?

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket

I've been using Bitbucket for a few months now. I was asked to restrict developers from merging with develop branch unless they're the lead developers.

I created a branch restriction in develop branch. This works fine when feature branch cannot merge with develop branch without the lead developers approving and merging them.

Feature branch does not have any branch restrictions.

However, we have another branch called backlog. The backlog branch also has branch restriction just like develop.

When we tried to merge develop to backlog, it requires permission from lead developer which is fine. However, even lead developer cannot merge it.

I'm thinking, is it possible to exempt merge permission from develop to backlog and vice versa? Any branches wanting to merge with develop needs permission.

Comment: > _However, even lead developer cannot merge it_ - and what does Bitbucket display as the reason? Also, just curious, what is _backlog_ branch for in your case? It's not a conventional branch name used in Git flow or TBD.

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev On the Bitbucket log, it says that the lead developer does not have the right permission to merge even though he's is one of the group of people who can merge it. 

Backlog branch isn't a conventional branch in Git, this branch acts as a way to connect it to another separate repo. So, we have two repos and Backlog acts like a "bridge" to bring over the code changes made by the other repo. 

If it's not possible to selectively exempt branches because Bitbucket isn't designed this way, then I'll accept that as an answer as well.